# Superscript in a yaml file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, haml

I currently have an en.yaml file with the key title: ForestTheTrade® but when I see the text on the front end of my app the ® does not get super scripted and it looks like regular text. how can I super script the ® in the text so I can see it as super script on the front end>

lmk if more info is needed and I can provide it

Comment: The front-end is... HTML ? You can try to replace ® by `<sup>&reg;</sup>` in your YAML file but it might not work if your front-end server escapes the displayed content.

Comment: @Fravadona should I have a key "reg: ®" as well? This is in a ruby app and I believe the view is made through a haml file. I am happy to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

You can add html into the string like @Fravadona recommends, you just would have to add `.html_safe` after to tell the app you don't want the html escaped.

Comment: so it would be ```title: ("FoestTheTrader<sup>®</sup>").html_safe```

Comment: Not quite, you'd use `html_safe` where you are requesting the content. I'm guessing you're utiliznig i18n files. So it'll probably look something like `t('title').html_safe`

Comment: @MattPolito There is  the title:
title: 59 2 in the power of (4-1) Fractional Design.

I tried this following in yaml:

`title: t('59 2<sup>4-1</sup> Fractional Design').html_safe`

It did not work.